# Removing multiple occurrence of an element from the given dataset

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataset as follows:

| Name | Elements |
| --- | --- |
| Cat | friend, friend, friend |
| Dog | friend, friend |
| Crow | friend |
| Cow | friend, domestic |
| Parrot | friend, friend, domestic, domestic |
| Rabbit | domestic |

I have to remove all the rows containing only the occurrence of friend in element column.
That is my final output should look like:

| Name | Elements |
| --- | --- |
| Cow | friend, domestic |
| Parrot | friend, friend, domestic, domestic |
| Rabbit | domestic |

I tried it by creating a list and then removing it using the following method, the code is as follows:

```
list = list(data["Elements"])
list[:] = [x for x in list if x != 'friend']
```

But using the above code only one instance, containing friend once i.e. Element corresponding to crow gets deleted and am unable to map the remaining data to the corresponding 'Name' Column.

How to remove all the instances of friend i.e. the elements corresponding to Cat, Dog and Crow. Also how would I be able to map the data to the corresponding 'Name' Column?

Any other methods?

Please guide.

Comment: please avoid using builtin `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the list of elements to a set, which is a object that is similar to a list but can't have duplicates (among other features).
replacing it with

```
list[:] = [x for x in list if set(x) != set('friend')]
```

In order to remove the corresponding name, it might be better to not use list comprehension and instead use a for loop, like so (Output in form of two lists)

```py
for name, element in zip(data["Name"], data["Elements"]):
    if set(element.split(", ")) != set(["friend"]) and element != "friend":
         cleanList.append((name,element))

cleanList = list(zip(*cleanList))

print(cleanList)
```

Comment: I tried using it too, but was unable to get it done and wasn't able to map the data to corresponding 'Name' Column. Any other suggestions?

This is what i tried:                                                                                                                                                      
                                             set = set(data["Element"])
                                                  set.remove('Friend')

Comment: @AdiG Sorry didn't see you edit, I included a version of code that should work, I tested it and it works

Comment: got the following error: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @AdiG just to clarify, is the data set of dictionary of two lists? When I tried it worked fine. Here is the replit where it works: [replit](https://replit.com/@ThomasBaeyens/cleanList#listCleaner.py)

Comment: I am importing the dataframe using pd.read_excel function

Comment: @AdiG This code should work, but you may have to convert the output list back to a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that there are possibly going to be more types of elements and possibly rows with no elements.

I am assuming that df['elements'] is a string (since you don't give a code example to see the formatting). The list will be [item.strip() for item in df['elements'].split(',')].

I would then convert the list to a set and see if is {'friend'}

```
def make_set(s):
    return set([item.strip() for item in s.split(',')])
cond = df['elements'].apply(lambda s: make_set(s) != {'friend'})
df[cond]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
ix = df['Elements'].str.split(r',\s*', regex=True).apply(set) != {'friend'}
newdf = df.loc[ix].reset_index(drop=True).copy()

>>> newdf
     Name                            Elements
0     Cow                    friend, domestic
1  Parrot  friend, friend, domestic, domestic
2  Rabbit                            domestic
```

Note: if you are using `pandas < 1.4` (you shouldn't), then remove the `regex=True` argument:

```py
ix = df['Elements'].str.split(r',\s*').apply(set) != {'friend'}
```

#### Explanations

The first part `str.split(...)` splits the text values in `Elements` into lists. We apply `set` to those lists to obtain sets. And then we make a mask `ix` where these sets are different than the singleton `{'friend'}`.

The second part selects according to that mask, resets the `RangeIndex` so that you get rows `0, 1, 2...`. The final bit `.copy()` is to ensure that the `newdf` has its own data and is not merely a slice in the original. This helps if you are going to modify it further.

Comment: Getting the following error: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'

Comment: what pandas version are you using?

Comment: pandas version 1.3.4

Comment: see updated response

Comment: did you try without the `regex` argument? Does this help?